# reducer/action not updating slice

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am clearly missing something about how this should work. I have a slice, it has reducers I can bring those in and I can see console.log firing as expected... buuut Redux Dev Tools says I have not changed my state - the default null still is still the listed value.

Slice

```
import { User } from "@firebase/auth";
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

//Slice definition
// define state
interface UserState {
  currentUser: User | null;
}
const initialState: UserState = {
  currentUser: null,
};

//define action creators
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser(state, action: PayloadAction<User>) {
      state.currentUser = action.payload;
    },
    setNoUser(state) {
      state.currentUser = null;
    },
  },
});
//export all action creators
export const { setUser, setNoUser } = userSlice.actions;

//export reducer that handles all actions
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "../features/user/user-slice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { user: userReducer },
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

App snippet

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
...
import { setUser, setNoUser } from "./features/user/user-slice";

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("useEffect");
        console.log(user);
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setNoUser();
        console.log("useEffect, no user");
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });
  });
  if (loading) return <Spinner animation="border" color="dark" />;
  return <App/>;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason for this is because setUser is an action and the action needs to be dispatched.

Per Mark Erikson's [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zySeP5vH9c&t=3699s) from may it is advisable to create a typed version of the useSelector and useDispatch hooks when working with typescript.

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState, AppDispatch } from "./store";

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const userAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

you then import the hooks from the hooks file not react-redux and dispatch or select from there:

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
dispatch(setUser(auth.currentUser));
```